# Comparing two CSV files in powershell and creating an output

Tags: powershell

I'm currently working on a script to import 2 csv files, compare the fqdn columns and output the results to a file.

The issue is after many hours of testing I'm at the point that it looks like my script is working up until the point of getting the path for each file that needs to be imported but I can't seem to get the `import-csv` command to do what I need it to.

I'd appreciate any guidance you can provide.

My script so far and the error I'm getting are below:

```
$CMDB_Installed = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\nha1\Desktop\Reports\CMDBInstall | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -expa FullName -First 1 | Out-String

$SCOM_AgentList = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\nha1\Desktop\Reports\SCOMUAT | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -expa FullName -First 1 | Out-String



$SL = Import-Csv $SCOM_AgentList

$CL = Import-Csv $CMDB_Installed



Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CL -DifferenceObject $SL -Property fqdn |

Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path = C:\Users\nha1\Desktop\Reports\AuditOutput\UATNeedsAgent+SCOM\UATHosts-NotinSCOM$(get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd).csv
```

Error Message:

```
import-csv : Illegal characters in path.

At line:4 char:7

+ $SL = import-csv $SCOM_AgentList

+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], ArgumentException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand


import-csv : Illegal characters in path.

At line:5 char:7

+ $CL = import-csv $CMDB_Installed

+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], ArgumentException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $CMDB_Installed = ... | Select -expa FullName -First 1 | Out-String
> ```

**Don't use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string)**, *unless* you want a *for-display*, *multi-line* string representation.

**Your file-path variables therefore contain *newlines*** (line breaks), which `Import-Csv` complains about, given that newlines in file names are illegal in NTFS (on Windows).

---

Simply *omit* the `Out-String` call, given that `Select -expa FullName -First 1` by definition already outputs a string (given that the `.FullName` property on the objects output by `Get-ChildItem` is `[string]`-typed).

---

To recreate the problem:

```
PS> Import-Csv "foo`n"  # illegal line break in file path
Import-Csv : Illegal characters in path.
```

To demonstrate that `Out-String` produces a multi-line string even with a single-line string as input:

```
PS> ('foo' | Out-String).EndsWith("`n")
True
```